# Properly calculating the time taken to generate a page by PHP

Tags: php, php-7

I am using the following code to calculate time taken by PHP to generate a page.

```
<?php echo (microtime(true) - $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT']);?>
```

I put this code just before the closing `body` tag so I am assuming the result would be accurate enough.

The value returned by this code is: 0.4458909034729 and other similar values.

I have read the PHP documentation and some other articles but I am not completely sure if the returned value is in seconds, milliseconds or microseconds.

An explanation would be very helpful to me and other fellow beginners. :)

Comment: `0.4458909034729` is almost half a second.

Comment: Well, it is 0.445 seconds or 445ms.    Unix time is always in seconds, microsecond precision is referring to the decimals.

Comment: I bet you need to read documentation __again__ and more carefully.

Comment: @u_mulder I have but I could not get any definite answers. From my understanding, microsecond - microsecond = microsecond. However, `0.4458909034729` would be way too fast for microseconds.

So, I got confused.

Comment: So dump original values and check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documentation:

1. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

> 'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'
>       The timestamp of the start of the request, with **microsecond** precision. Available since PHP 5.4.0.

2. http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

> `microtime` — Return current Unix timestamp with **microseconds**

But, let's do some check. create a simple script:

```
sleep(2);
$t = microtime(true);
var_dump(
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'], 
    $t, 
    $t - $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT']
);
```

Result on my machine is:

```
float(1525895588.0071) 
float(1525895590.0074) 
float(2.0003039836884)
```

As we can see - values are **seconds** (`1525895588`) with **microsecond** part (`0071`). And diff seems correct - our script sleeps for **2** seconds.

So, the result of your substraction is **seconds**. And in your example your script runs half of a second, **not** half of a microsecond.

Comment: Is my page actually being parsed so quickly by PHP? This would mean that I could parse more than 1000000 pages in a second. That's why I wanted to ask the experts and make sure I am not misreading the values. :)